# Вызов формы редактирования при переходе между textbox's (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме имеются textbox's, мне необходимо при переходе между ними по нажатию на Tab и получении фокуса, что бы запускалась форма редактирования. Когда я перехожу на нужный мне textbox вызов формы зацикливается. Я подписался на событие GotFocus. Как правильно изменить такое поведение?

Подписка на событие получения фокуса:

```
this.RtbSupplyStandards.GotFocus += (sender, args) => GetInfoQuantityByOrder?.Invoke(null, null);
```

Обработчик:

```
private void View_GetInfoQuantityByOrder(object sender, QuantityByNorm e)
        {
            try
            {
                double resultCalculate = 0;

                var arg = new List<object>() { _quantityByOrder, _year, _isCentralElement };
                if (_isCentralElement)
                    arg.Add(_departmentId);
                var editData = Controller.Run<MessageDataEditorPresenter, List<object>>(arg);

                var result = editData.QuantityByOrders;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in result)
                    {
                        resultCalculate += item.ProductCount;
                    }
                }

                _requestReportRecord.ReqByNormCount = resultCalculate;
                View.UpdateDataSupplyStandards(resultCalculate);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _log.Error(exception, "Ошибка записи в отчёт.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @AlexF так а как потом повторно вернуться на нужный textbox, если там будет переменная что данный элементы уже был в фокусе?

Comment: @AlexF добавил код.